# how to remove the column with all the same elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Suppose the input is:

```
[1 2 3;
 2 3 3;
 3 4 3;
 3 5 3;]
```

The expected output would be:

```
[1 2;
 2 3;
 3 4;
 3 5;]
```

The reason to remove the third column is because all the elements in the third column is the same. Is there a default matlab function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A(:,sum(abs(diff(A)))>0,1)
```

"Keep the columns where the difference is larger than zero"

Comment: way simpler than mine :)

Comment: Incorrect if `A = [1 2 3]` or `A = [1 2 3; 2  3 3]`.

Comment: should be 'A( :, sum( abs(diff(A)) )>0, 1 )'.

Answer (score 1):

Both the posted answers are incorrect. Test the edge cases where `A` only has 1 or 2 rows:

i.e:

```
A = [1 2 3];
```

or:

```
A = [1 2 3; 
     2  3 3];
```

`diff` and `any` need to be supplied with the correct dimension:

```
A = A(:,any(diff(A,1,1),1));
```

This outputs:

```
A = [1 2 3; 2 3 3];
EDU>> A(:,any(diff(A,1,1),1))

ans =

     1     2
     2     3
```

and

```
A = [1 2 3]
EDU>> A(:,any(diff(A,1,1),1))

ans =

   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

Also, IMO this, semantically, makes the most sense:

```
A(:,all(bsxfun(@eq,A,A(1,:)),1)) = []
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning to this specific case. However, in my task, the input matrix would always has more than one rows, since if it has only one row, it would not have a column which has all the same elements.

Comment: The accepted answer is still wrong for the case of two rows. `A = [1 2 3;      2  3 3]`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
A =

     1     2     3
     2     3     3
     3     4     3
     3     5     3

B = A==repmat(A(1,:),size(A,1),1)

B =

     1     1     1
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
     0     0     1

C = sum(B) == size(A,1)

C =

     0     0     1

A(:,C) =[]

A =

     1     2
     2     3
     3     4
     3     5
```

In one line:

```
A(:, sum(A==repmat(A(1,:),size(A,1),1)) == size(A,1)) = []
```

Comment: @jucestain what would be your idea of a "correct" result if there is only one row?

Comment: Every element in each column is the same, so it should return an empty vector. This is known as the reflexive property of the equality operator.